# How to sort joined table results?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-order-by

My models:

```
namespace Music.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Music.Models
{
    public class Song
    {
        public int SongID { get; set; }
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is show a specified album with its songs. I want to sort the songs by `TrackNumber`. Tried like this:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
    album.Songs.OrderBy(s => s.TrackNumber);
    return View(album);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I feel stupid for now being able to find it on the web, but wasn't able to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `OrderBy` but the returned ordered enumerable is "lost".

You could add an an getter in your `Album` class which returns the sorted Tracks.

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<Song> SortedSongs {
        get { return Songs.OrderBy(s => s.TrackNumber); }
    }
}
```

You can have this getter in a partial class, if your model class is generated.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a neat way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In linq, you usually have to assign the result of an operator, like:

```
album.Songs = album.Songs.OrderBy(s => s.TrackNumber);
```

The `OrderBy` creates a new orderred collection; it does not overwrite the original unless you tell it to.

Comment: Doesn't it require a conversion to `ICollection<Song>`? Thought `IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>` only inherits `IEnumerable<TElement>`.